# Installing rstan crashes Rstudio

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, rstan

I'm trying installing `rstan` using
`install.packages('rstan')`

It gets laggy and then automatically closes Rstudio. I have tried
`install.packages(c("BH", "StanHeaders", "Rcpp", "RcppEigen", "RcppParallel", "inline", "loo", "pkgbuild"))` but that didn't help.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

What else could I try?

Comment: what happens if you try doing it via command line?

Comment: if it crashes then, then the issue is with R. If not, then the issue is with RStudio

Comment: What is the correct way to try that? Should I ` sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpp r-cran-inline r-cran-rcpp ` in the terminal?